# Walking with HTC controllers attached to the feet on Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

I would like to attached htc vive controller to the feet of a person so that it's walk is perfectly render in Unity. 
Do you guys know any existing scripts or have any clue where I should be looking to achieve that ?

Thanks a lot.

Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to use [Inverse Kinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html)

I never used it before but there is a lot of tutorials about how to use this